# Taxonomy filter under Polylang

Tags: query, plugin-polylang

The filter code below is from Themeskingdom [Exclusy](http://themeskingdom.com/wordpress-themes/exclusy-responsive-portfolio-theme/) theme. It makes a sql query for posts ids and then queries the taxonomy terms associated with those posts. I then uses isotope jquery plugin to serve a list of years (the terms) that the user can filter the posts by. My problem is that I'm creating a bilingual site with [Polylang](http://polylang.wordpress.com/). And, although, when I'm in the english version of the site, I get just a list of english language posts, I get all the years available for filtering, from both english and native language posts. 
I believe I must replace that sql query with a query that takes polylang's [`lang` parameter](http://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/general/), and enclose it with a current locale conditional. But I need a query function that can return ids so I don't change the original too much. Or is there a simpler way?
Thank you,

```
<div class="gallery-filter left">
            <span><?php _e('Filter:', tk_theme_name) ?></span>
            <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active-project active"><?php _e('All', tk_theme_name) ?></a>
            <?php
            global $wpdb;
            $gallery_orderby = get_theme_option(tk_theme_name . '_gallery_gallery_orderby');
            $gallery_order = get_theme_option(tk_theme_name . '_gallery_gallery_order');
            $post_type_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'texto' AND post_status = 'publish'");
            if (!empty($post_type_ids)) {
                $post_type_cats = wp_get_object_terms($post_type_ids, 'ano', array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'DESC', 'fields' => 'ids', 'hide_empty' => true ));
                if ($post_type_cats) {
                    $post_type_cats = array_unique($post_type_cats);
                }
            }
            $include_category = null;
            if (!empty($post_type_ids)) {
                foreach ($post_type_cats as $category_list) {
                    $cat = $category_list . ",";
                    $include_category = $include_category . $cat;
                    $cat_name = get_term($category_list, 'ano');
                    ?>
                    <a href="#" data-filter="<?php echo '.class-' . $category_list ?>"><?php echo $cat_name->name ?></a>
                <?php }
            } ?>
</div><!--/gallery-filter-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. With help from this answer: [get all posts ID from a category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71471/get-all-posts-id-from-a-category/71473#71473)

```
$post_type_ids = get_posts(array(
'numberposts'   => -1, // get all posts.
'post_type' => 'texto',
'fields'        => 'ids', // Only get post IDs
  ));
```