# Get post ids from WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

Is there a way I can retrieve an array of post ids queried from the following:

```
$latest = new WP_Query( array (
    'orderby'               => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page'        => 3
));

if ( $latest -> have_posts() ) : while ( $latest -> have_posts() ) : $latest -> the_post();

    get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'post' );

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
```

---

**Follow Up:**

I used `wp_list_pluck` to retrieve an array of post ids:

```
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $latest->posts, 'ID' );
```

Then converted the array into a string using the implode function:

```
$post_ids_string = implode( ',', $post_ids );
```

Sorry for the ambiguous question.

Comment: rick, your question is ambiguous. Please be very clear what you want before posting a question. This will save everyone from answering irrelevant stuff. You actually need the post ID's returned in a string, **not an array**

Comment: Your `wp_reset_postdata` should be inside not outside the if statement, otherwise you might reset post data when it hasn't been changed

Comment: If you're only wanting the IDs, you should seriously consider s_ha_dum's answer. That will return the IDs without also retrieving lots of other data from the database that you then throw away.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try

```
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $latest->posts, 'ID' );
```

Read [`wp_list_pluck`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck)

Comment: This can be useful if you also need the whole data for each post, not just the posts ids. Otherwise, I'd go with @s-ha-dum's solution.

Answer (score 134):

Use the `fields` argument in your query.

> fields (string) - Which fields to return. All fields are returned by
>   default. There are two other options:
>    - 'ids' - Return an array of post IDs.
>    - 'id=>parent' - Return an associative array [ parent => ID, … ].
>
> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter

```
$latest = new WP_Query( array (
    'orderby'               => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page'        => 3,
    'fields' => 'ids'
));
var_dump($latest->posts);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it only queries the ID's making it a lot faster than quering everyhing and than 'plucking' (loop and re-storing) it in a new array.

Comment: Perhaps you need to get IDs AFTER normal wp_query has already been executed, for example when you merge two queries afterwards and need ID's to exclude results from previous query.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution, among the answers to this question, this is the most efficient.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer 100%

Answer (score 6):

I suggest this solution

```
get_posts([
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_type' => 'some-custom-post-type',
  'fields' => 'ids',
]);
```

and as return you have array with ids inside ;)

```
array (size=5)
  0 => int 81002
  1 => int 77885
  2 => int 77180
  3 => int 74722
  4 => int 73312
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the solution from @s-ha-dum is economical if you only need to get the id's, and you don't have previous query object set.

Here is why:

```
switch ( $q['fields'] ) {
    case 'ids':
        $fields = "$wpdb->posts.ID";
        break;
    case 'id=>parent':
        $fields = "$wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_parent";
        break;
    default:
        $fields = "$wpdb->posts.*";
```

Because in the case you only specify `'fields' => 'ids'` nothing more you will get in return than the ID's.

If you would go with `'fields' => 'id=>parent'` (Looks really funny) you will get also the parent ID's.

Any other way using `'fields'` argument will not have any impact as of WordPress v4.7.

But in case you have the query as in the example `wp_list_pluck` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the get_the_ID() function? Just sharing the loop code and it shows all post ids in the query.

```
// The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();     
                    
            echo '<li>' . get_the_ID() . '</li>';
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
        $string = "no posts found";
    }
```

Comment: I think the goal was probably to get the IDs in an array to do something else with, not to actually display them. Using the loop for that feels like overkill.